# Weird behavior when writing to SD card programmatically in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app that is supposed to record videos and store them on the SD card, and then read and upload them to a server. It works perfectly fine for the devices that come with an SD card (when purchased). However, on my smartphone I added an external SD card I owned before. And for some reason the app does not store the recorded videos on the SD card, but on the internal storage instead. I traced the logcat output and there's no indication on why this is happening, and there are no exceptions. And it's causing me problems because the uploader still tries to read from the SD card and the files aren't even there, which gives me an exception for this part.
Can someone help me figure out why this happens?

P.S. I can write on the SD card using USB or by simply saving photos and files from other apps, it just doesn't work for this app I'm building.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for writing to the SD card?

Comment: I hope you haven't hard coded the path for the sdcard. You should access it via `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) for more info.